# Swift UIView zPosition issue, views overlap on other views

Tags: swift, uiview, layer, zposition

I am writing a calendar view, I added three other views to its super view, so the calendar view should be on the topper layer, it looks fine on the simulator

[image: On simulator]

but later on, I found that I can't click the button, then I checked the view hierarchy, found that the other three views overlap on the calendar, it is so weird as the 3d preview and view on the simulator are different

[image: On Hierarchy Debugger]

Here is the code of UI Part

func updateUI() {

```
    if calendarView != nil {

        self.view.addSubview(calendarView!)

        self.calendarView!.frame.origin = calendarViewPosition!
        self.calendarView!.layer.zPosition = 5
        self.calendarView!.layer.cornerRadius = self.setting.itemCardCornerRadius
        self.calendarView!.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.calendarView!.setViewShadow()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.calendarView!.frame.origin.y += 50
        }) { _ in
            
            var newCalendarPageCordiateYDifference: CGFloat = 10
            var newCalendarPageSizeDifference: CGFloat = 20
            var zPosition: CGFloat = 4
            
            for _ in 1 ... 3 {
                let newCalendarPage = UIView()
            
                newCalendarPage.frame = CGRect(x: self.calendarView!.frame.origin.x + newCalendarPageSizeDifference / 2, y: self.calendarView!.frame.origin.y, width: self.calendarView!.frame.width - newCalendarPageSizeDifference, height: self.calendarView!.frame.height - newCalendarPageSizeDifference)
                newCalendarPage.backgroundColor = .white
                newCalendarPage.layer.zPosition = zPosition
                newCalendarPage.layer.cornerRadius = self.setting.itemCardCornerRadius
                newCalendarPage.setViewShadow()
                
                self.view.addSubview(newCalendarPage)
                
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    newCalendarPage.frame.origin.y -= newCalendarPageCordiateYDifference
                })
                
                zPosition -= 1
                newCalendarPageCordiateYDifference += 10
                newCalendarPageSizeDifference += 50
            }
            
           
        }
    }
    
    
   
    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `self.view.addSubview(newCalendarPage)` this from for loop and
Add subview like this

```
self.view.insertSubview(newCalendarPage, belowSubview: calendarView)
```

Another way is to disable user interaction like
`newCalendarPage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`